# Azure + ASP.Net + System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Content/img/CourseImages' is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, file-upload, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload an file using asp.net on azure (its not VM).
But constantly, i am receiving below error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Content/img/CourseImages' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
string courseImageFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CourseImage"];
string courseImageFilePath = Path.Combine(courseImageFolderPath, fileName);
if (!Directory.Exists(courseImageFolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(courseImageFolderPath);
courseImage.SaveAs(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(courseImageFilePath));
```

Comment: Why are you saving the images in the webapps itself ? I think you don't have permissions to save images into the app service location. If you want to upload images you can use blob container (or) some other storage accounts. Azure Web App is a PaaS model where you just host your code and not for uploading image there itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Azure Web App has a local directory(`D:\local`) which is temporary. The content in this folder will be deleted when the run is no longer running on the VM. This directory is a place to store temporary data for the application. It is not recommended to use this folder by your web application.

According to [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#file-system-restrictionsconsiderations), I suggest you create a temp folder at the root of your web application folder(`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) and use it to store the temp data. Or as jayendran said, you could use [blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=net) to upload your image.

```
string tempFolder = Server.MapPath("~/TEMP");
if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
}
```

For more detials, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415284/access-to-the-path-is-denied-an-exception-of-type-system-unauthorizedaccessexc).

Also, it seems that the app service do not get access to network resource. So what you would do is impersonate a user that has access on the network resource in order to create the directory. Please refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp-net-application).

Comment: Yes, created container and blob and able to upload and download files. However,  How log4net  is able to create file and able to  write on server? Because I was uploading a file whereas log4net is creating a text file on the same location.

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this [article](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/community/developers-club/blog/2016/05/10/adding-logging-to-a-net-application-using-log4net).